# Search jobs by Location does not work

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I open Stackoverflow pages it shows me some jobs near Tehran, Iran.
[image]

But when I go to Jobs Page and search for Jobs near Tehran or Iran, I see nothing.

[image]

Is there any problem with search jobs by location?

Comment: no repro here, 5 jobs near Tehran, Iran. Can you try again? http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=tehran&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles

Comment: This happens to me as well.  Looking for jobs in Calgary, Alberta, I can see that there are quite a few because many are suggested, and I can click on the links to see them.  But when I search by location I only see two.

Comment: @Max again 0 jobs near Tehran, Iran.

Comment: Are jobs targeted to user location? I can't provide an example at the moment but crawlers like [this](https://whoishiring.io/) can find some jobs that I can't.

Comment: i can't see any jobs near tehran when i search jobs by location yet

Comment: No jobs in Teheran, neither on Jobs nor on Careers for me. Maybe cache?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs The problem is i see jobs (as you can see in first pic) for a week but when i click on "Jobs near you" i see nothing. even if i search for jobs in Tehran or Iran. But yes maybe its cache.

Comment: @Milad were you using a proxy or VPN at the time? If I pretend to be coming from your IP address in Iran I see the listings. If you were coming from an IP address that is not in the Middle East (which is where these listings are targeted) you won't see them. This is by design - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217857/more-job-results-behind-proxy-in-england/217891#217891

Comment: @DeanWard That's odd. It seems to me that if you're searching for jobs in a specific region, jobs that are targeted at that region _should_ be included. Why should it matter where SO thinks the computer you're using happens to be located at the time of the search? E.g. If I'm on a business trip to France, I won't be able to see jobs targeted at my hometown in the US, even if I explicitly search for them? That doesn't seem like correct behavior to me, regardless of whether or not it's intentional.

Comment: @Ajedi32 it's more complicated than that and, trust me, it has been a heavily discussed topic. TL;DR: we've had employers that were getting applications from outside of their region or country that they simply cannot act upon - either due to not allowing remote or because they don't provide visa sponsorship. If an employer checks the 'visa sponsorship' button on the job then it is, by default (the employer can change it), visible worldwide. Obviously this becomes an issue for those travelling, but we considered that enough of an edge case to not worry about it....

Comment: @Ajedi32 so it's by-design for now. At least until we get feedback that completely invalidates that decision

Comment: Ok, but doing this by IP address is flakey.  I'm sitting in Calgary, but happen to be connected to a corporate VPN that pegs me as being in England - this results in me getting a filtered list of 2 jobs.  When i'm travelling in Germany on vacation, I'm stunned to find that all the jobs in Calgary are gone, when I finally have time to look at jobs.  At least I know why now...

Comment: I take back part of my previous comment.  I'm now using a Calgary IP address, I've set my location in my account to Calgary, but I only see 2 Calgary jobs.  So the location filter looks broken

Comment: @DeanWard this means you're potentially hiding an opening in Luxembourg from a jobseeker in Trier, Germany (46 km, a 40 minute commute, plus an automatic cross-border right to work, no visa required) while showing them one in Munich (507 km) just because it happens to be in the same country. You can come up with any number of similar scenarios all over the continent. It seems insane and counterproductive, even when discarding people on vacations.

Comment: @Pekka that's certainly possible, but pretty much all our employers that post jobs for the EU also make their jobs visible in the EU. We automatically select the most appropriate targeting preferences based upon whether the employer allows remote or relocation and whether they allow visa sponsorship. In general that means all employers in the EU have their jobs visible in the EU, not just the country they are based in.

Comment: @Arunas there are currently only 3 jobs in the board within 50 miles of Calgary that are targeted worldwide, out of 11 total. I'll check out your IP address details on Monday to work out why Maxmind thinks you're not in Canada (the only reason you'd see 2 rather than all the listings).

Comment: @dean ward, Thanks for looking into it.  This is pretty wild.  From my mac on my Telus DSL address, I only get 3 jobs listed.  My iPhone, using Fido (Rogers) shows me 11.  My iPad, over Wifi (using DSL) or Telus Cellular or Fido (via wifi hotspot using my iPhone) only shows 3.  So there's some sort of memory here.

Comment: @Arunas logged in using the same user?

Comment: @Dean Ward, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, region-specific listings aside, we did actually have an underlying issue here.

When testing for these kinds of issues we effectively impersonate your IP address and check all the routes that could be affected by this.

Unfortunately the bug for this was in a code path that was never hit when we impersonate. I'm getting our support team (and devs!) to use a VPN to the relevant location in future which makes reproducing such issues less likely to fail.

Thanks for the report, build has been pushed to production now.

Comment: Cool!  I look forward to testing it!

Comment: That's Perfect I really appreciate.

Comment: @Dean Ward,  Thanks, that seems to have fixed things for me!

Answer (score 10):

> We've had employers that were getting
>   applications from outside of their region or country that they simply
>   cannot act upon - either due to not allowing remote or because they
>   don't provide visa sponsorship. If an employer checks the 'visa
>   sponsorship' button on the job then it is, by default (the employer
>   can change it), visible worldwide. Obviously this becomes an issue for
>   those travelling, but we considered that enough of an edge case to not
>   worry about it.... – Dean Ward♦ 5 hours ago

Yes, it's an edge case, but that doesn't justify having your UI lie to those users. Also, your solution is only halfway complete since "Jobs near you" doesn't implement it at all yet (otherwise, it would match the results from the same search query). So that means that those employers are probably still getting many resumes from abroad that they can not act upon.

In any case, if employers are worried about getting job applications from outside their region, then at least tell the job hunters in question that their query got "y number of results and x number of hidden results", and that those hidden results will remain hidden until they can do the query again from inside the country/region in question. Basically, anything would be better than misleading those users and making them think that the site is broken, or empty of jobs.

After all, it's not just travelers that are going to run into this problem. Your own paying customers, HR representatives and management from large conglomerates in different regions may run into this issue. Developers from Iran/China/Dubai/Turkey/etc with a US-based proxy (for reliable access to github or youtube) may run into this.

And I've also run into this issue, although I am just realizing it now!

When I run an empty search query on Oakland, California (which is where I live), I get 220 job listings. And when I run an empty search query on London, UK, I get 24 job listings (which doesn't make sense, London should have many more jobs than Oakland).

Seriously guys. Many of us are foreign-born, and sometimes we're just curious about the number of similar jobs in our home country. Please fix your UI. I know that misleading your user base seems like the easiest shortcut right now, but that's not a viable longterm strategy. You've solved other conceptual problems that were one hundred times harder to fix than this one.

Also, if your site has a distinguishing feature that makes you better than other job boards, by filtering out a flood of unusable resumes, then you should showcase that feature to as many people as you can, and not keep it hidden. For instance, the biggest selling point of nextdoor.com (a neighborhood social platform) is that they do the verification of addresses before they give access to anything and what they give you access to is limited to the neighborhood you reside in. Now imagine if they were to just filter forum results based on geolocation without telling anyone what they're doing, many people just wouldn't bother registering with them or advertising with them thinking that the platform was a thousand times smaller than it seemed. And not knowing about that filtering policy, that feature would seem more like a bug, not a positive feature at all. That being said, that feature is their unique selling proposition. It's what makes them different from Facebook, Twitter, and Google+ and it's the reason users recommend that platform to others.

Comment: "Jobs near you" *does* implement this. I'm confirming with the team whether there's a bug there.

Comment: No bug so far as I can see. We're discussing better ways of doing this rather than your IP address. Perhaps locations that you state you have a work visa/permit for instead...

Comment: @DeanWard, May be you should ping Milad for more details. It could just be the "Jobs near you" that's caching the results of a previous geolocation query from the last time the search page was used. In which case, such a behavior would only show up right after crossing a border, or right after using a VPN/proxy.

Answer (score 9):

Someone in a far away country might still have dual citizenship or work permit and be able to work in the target country. So this "hiding" essentially prevents them from applying.

What if I, from another country, want to help find a job for a friend (or myself) who *does* have the work permit in the target country?

Instead why not *ask* the employers to add a note/disclaimer in the job description itself rather than hiding it completely?

Such as:

> We can't provide VISA sponsorship for this job and won't consider
>   applications from those who are not eligible to work in [country].
>   Please refrain from applying if you can't obtain a work permit/VISA on your own.

and trust potential job seekers to do the right thing rather than trying to "work around" the problem by hiding it?
In fact, Stack Exchange can add such a disclaimer *by default* unless an employer "ticks" the VISA sponsorship box and let the employers know that their ad won't visible outside of their region.

The example cases mentioned by me and others here may very well be corner cases. But it does seem to be overly employer friendly because they can't be bothered to add a note in the job description or process/reject applications from outside of their region/country.

Comment: "We can't provide VISA sponsorship for this job and won't consider applications from those who are not eligible to work in [country]. Please refrain from applying if you can't obtain a work permit/VISA on your own." best suggestion ever